# Memory, CPU and network usage measurement and comparison tools

Tags: android

My application is content and functionality complete and I want to profile real test data. DDMS debugging tools are IMHO not a reliable source, you need to be plugged in to the computer and have the debugger meddling to test, which throws off measurements.

Which tools can be used to profile application consumption, and maybe report it and compare with older revisions?

Comment: Any testing requires something "meddling to test", by definition.